# Python: Parsing a dir of txt files, saving lines containing string to new directory, ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python

```
import os
import sys

a = os.listdir("C:\\Python27\\forms2")

i = 0

big_file = open("c:\\Python27\\forms2\\%s" %a[i], 'r')
small_file3 = open("c:\\Python27\\forms3\\%s" %a[i], 'w')
linez = big_file.read()
for line in linez:
   if 'TextControl' in linez:
      small_file3.write(line)

   if 'http://' in linez:
      small_file3.write(line)
   i = i + 1
   big_file.close()
   small_file3.close()
```

Output is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\testreadwrite", line 13, in <module>
    small_file3.write(line)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

"testreadwrite" is the name of the script. Why is it injecting where it should be injecting the 'a' list var?

Comment: And? Why do you call close() inside the loop and not finally *once* after the loop?

Comment: This is a pretty clear case of reading the error message - it says the file is closed, and you clearly close it. Don't close it inside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are closing the file at the end of the `for` loop

```
for line in linez:
   ...
   big_file.close()
   small_file3.close()
```

you should close the files *after* the `for` loop

```
for line in linez:
   ...
big_file.close()
small_file3.close()
```

---

You can use a [context manager](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) to avoid such problems in the future:

```
with open("c:\\Python27\\forms2\\%s" %a[i], 'r') as big_file, \
     open("c:\\Python27\\forms3\\%s" %a[i], 'w') as small_file3:
    linez = big_file.read()
    for line in linez:
       ...
```

So you don't have to call `close` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling close() on the file descriptors inside the loop which makes zero 
sense. You likely want to close the file descriptors outside/after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

```
   I/O operation on closed file
```

tells you the problem, you are trying to perform an IO action on closed file, in this case write to a closed file.

The problem is that you are closing your output file (`"small_file3"`) *inside* the loop, you probably want to close it after the loop as already mentioned.

You could close your input (`"big_file"`) file just before the `for`-loop as you are done reading from it, and close your output file after the `for`-loop.

Also consider using [`os.path.join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html?highlight=os.path.join#os.path.join) to build your paths for opening your files.